# how to change new value from PropertyChangeEvent

Tags: java, listener, propertychangelistener

I have a preferences page in eclipse (IDE) and every time user change value from a property and click ok, those values are saved in a preferences files. I'm using a listener for getting new values. But what I need to do is get this new value -> process -> and save this new value processed and store in preference file. The implementation that I have is this:

```
public class PreferenceUtil extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

private StringFieldEditor stringUser;

@Override
public void init(IWorkbench arg0) {
    setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
}

@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {
stringUser = new StringFieldEditor("user", "&User:\t\t", getFieldEditorParent());

addField(stringUser);

Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {


@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (event.getProperty() == "user") {
                user = event.getNewValue().toString();                  
                //ConnectionValues.convert(user) is an algorithm that process a string
                stringUser.setStringValue(ConnectionValues.convert(user));                                      
            }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend 5 minutes to properly format your code to make our job easier. And btw: what exactly is your question? Do you expect us to figure where your code deviates from your requirements; so that we can do the rest of the work for you?

Comment: A) You asked 5 days ago. I told you after 10 minutes that your question has low quality; and surprise: you didn't receive any other feedback. No suggestions, no answers, nothing. And now you complain to the one person that told you "it wont work like this, you have to do something about it"? B) You come to this community because you want other people to help. But it seems that you dont care too much about the rules and policies of this community. And when you are told about your deficient input, you get rude. Are you sure that I am the "baby" in this conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, what I had to do is, create a StringFieldEditor and then use it in a listener for get the new value, process this value using my own algorithm for encrypt, then set this value encrypted to StringFieldEditor.

```
public class PreferenceUtil extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

StringFieldEditor secretSFE;

@Override
public void init(IWorkbench arg0) {
    setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
}


@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {

        secretSFE = new StringFieldEditor("secret", "&Secret:\t\t",getFieldEditorParent()){

        @Override
        protected void doFillIntoGrid(Composite parent, int numColumns) {
            super.doFillIntoGrid(parent, numColumns);

            getTextControl().setEchoChar('*');
        }

    };
    addField(secretSFE);

    Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if("secret".equalsIgnoreCase(event.getProperty())){
                String valueToEncrypt = (String)event.getNewValue();
                valueToEncrypt = ConnectionValues.convert(valueToEncrypt);
                secretFFE.setStringValue(valueToEncrypt);
            }
        }
    });      
  }
}
```